# Loop em Python pedindo reentrada de dados

Tags: python, array, lista, loop, numpy

Estou com um problema em meu código em Python, ele está dando loop. Toda vez tenho que inserir a lista novamente para mostrar os resultados.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statistics as st
from collections import defaultdict

lista = []


def vetor(lista):
    print('\nREGRAS NA FORMAÇÃO DA LISTA:\n'
          '1.Um dos valores tem que estar repetido\n'
          '2.O conjunto de dados deve apresentar, pelo menos, 6 valores únicos.\n'
          '3.NÃO É PERMITIDO escolher todos os números iguais.\n'
          '4.A LISTA POSSUI APENAS 12 ELEMENTOS\n')

    for i in range(0, 12):
        elementos = int(
            input('Elemento inserido no índice {}: '.format(i)))  
        lista.append(elementos)  
    return (lista)


print('A sua lista é: ', vetor(lista))
print('A média dos índices é: {:.4f} '.format(np.mean(vetor(lista))))
print('A moda é: {:.4f} '.format(st.mode(lista)))
print('A Mediana é: {:.4f} '.format(st.median(vetor(lista))))
print('A variância amostral é: {:.4f}'.format(st.pvariance(vetor(lista))))
print('O desvio padrão amostral é: {:.4f}'.format(st.stdev(vetor(lista))))
print('O coeficiente de variação é: {:.4f}'.format(st.variance(vetor(lista))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está chamando a função todas as vezes em que faz um `print()` nas ultimas linhas. Ou seja cada na primeira vez você vai chamar a função para "printar" 'A sua lista é: ', depois você chama ela de novo para "printar" 'A média dos índices é: {:.4f} '.

Você deveria salvar isso em um variavel assim no .format() você à colocaria. Por exemplo:

```py
valores = vetor(lista)

def vetor(lista):
    #código

print('A sua lista é: ', valores)
print('A média dos índices é: {:.4f} '.format(np.mean(valores)))
#continuação do código
```

Answer (score 2):

Mude o nome da função `vetor` para algo que deixe claro o intento de ler dados do usuário e armazene os resultados numa variável, garantindo que essa função seja chamada uma e somente uma vez. Por exemplo:

```py
import numpy as np
import statistics as st

def ler_dados():
    lista = []
    print('\nREGRAS NA FORMAÇÃO DA LISTA:\n'
          '1.Um dos valores tem que estar repetido\n'
          '2.O conjunto de dados deve apresentar, pelo menos, 6 valores únicos.\n'
          '3.NÃO É PERMITIDO escolher todos os números iguais.\n'
          '4.A LISTA POSSUI APENAS 12 ELEMENTOS\n')

    for i in range(0, 12):
        elemento = int(input('Elemento inserido no índice {}: '.format(i)))  
        lista.append(elemento)  
    return lista

lista = ler_dados()
print('A sua lista é: ', lista)
print('A média dos índices é: {:.4f} '.format(np.mean(lista)))
print('A moda é: {:.4f} '.format(st.mode(lista)))
print('A Mediana é: {:.4f} '.format(st.median(lista)))
print('A variância amostral é: {:.4f}'.format(st.pvariance(lista)))
print('O desvio padrão amostral é: {:.4f}'.format(st.stdev(lista)))
print('O coeficiente de variação é: {:.4f}'.format(st.variance(lista)))
```